# How do I find out which AWS Region an EBS snapshot lives?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot, regions

Is there any way to figure out which region an AWS EBS snapshot lives in?

A collaborator shared an ebs snapshot with me but I'm having a very slow transfer rate when I attached it to my instance (which is in USEAST-1d). I was wondering if the snapshot lived somewhere else but couldn't find a way to check it.

Comment: It is not possible to "attach" to an "EBS snapshot".  Please check your terminology and rephrase the question so that folks can help you solve your issue.  Perhaps you mean "EBS volume"?  Perhaps they shared an EBS snapshot with you, you created an EBS volume from the snapshot, and then you connected the snapshot to your instance?

Answer (score 2):

Snapshots operate on Amazon EC2 regional scope. You cannot create a volume from a snapshot residing in different region. Since you are able to create a volume in US-East-1A, i assume your snapshot also resides on US-East region.

Also as eric mentioned it is not possible to attach a snapshot to an EC2 directly, you have to create an EBS volume and then attach the volume to EC2 instance